# 3rd Degree Taylor Polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

So I'm trying to solve a 3rd degree polynomial
$$y′=t^2y−t $$
I'm not sure about how to proceed with the second order if $t$ will just become $2t$ and
$y$ will just become $2$ when you derive it.

The exact question is as follows:

> Find a 3rd degree Taylor polynomial for each that will approximate the solution to a given initial value problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i edited to clarify the question, i was also not exactly sure if it goes under differential equation but it seems so.

Comment: Hint: Assume that $y$ is analytics and has a power series representation around zero. Then what?

Comment: The question is asking you to substitute the form $y=a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3$ into the differential equation and solve for the coefficients $a_i$. Have you managed to do this? You can ignore terms in $t^4$ and higher (the reason for doing this is, essentially, the solution you get will be a good enough approximation to the exact solution of the differential equation as long as $t^4$ is small).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the initial point $t,y$, then you can compute
$$
y'=t^2y-t.
$$
From that you can compute the second derivative per
$$
y''=t^2y'+2ty-1
$$
and subsequently the third derivative
$$
y'''=t^2y''+4ty'+2y
$$
With these 3 values for the derivatives you can then compose the Taylor polynomial
$$
y(t+h)=y+hy'+\frac{h^2}2y''+\frac{h^3}6y'''
$$

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say the "Taylor polynomial" is centered at $0$.  Let's assume it is.
So we try to look for coefficients in
$y = a_0+a_1 t+a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3 + O(t^4)$
near $t=0$.  Using this, we get
\begin{align}
y'&=a_1+2 a_2 t + 3 a_3 t^2 + O(t^3)
\\
t^2 y - t &= - t + a_0 t^2+a_1 t^3+a_2 t^4 + a_3 t^5 + O(t^6)
\end{align}
In order for these to be identically equal, we require
\begin{align}
a_1 &= 0 ,
\\
2a_2 &= -1 ,
\\
3a_3 &= a_0 .
\end{align}
Thus, our approximation is
$$
y = a_0 -\frac{1}{2} t^2+\frac{a_0}{3} t^3 + O(t^4)
$$
If we are given an initial vaulue, we can use that for $a_0$.